# Почему не вызывается конструктор?

Tags: php, ооп

```
class InformationUser {

    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $photo;
    private $url;

    function _construct($data = array()){ var_dump($data); die(); // СЮДА НЕ ЗАХОДИТ
        $this->id    = $data['userinfo']['id'];
        $this->name  = $data['userinfo']['name'];
        $this->photo = $data['userinfo']['photo'];
        $this->url   = $data['userinfo']['url'];
    }

    function getUser(){
        return array(
            'id'    => $this->id,
            'name'  => $this->name,
            'photo' => $this->photo,
            'url'   => $this->url
        );
    }
}

class FeedTemplate {
 function __construct($data = array()){
        $this->data['user'] = $this->getUserInfo($data);
    }

    function getUserInfo($data){
        $user = new InformationUser($data);
        return $user->getUser();
    }

}
```

Почему-то при создании экземпляра класса **InformationUser** в методе другого класса не вызывается конструктор класса **InformationUser**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у вас construct в классе InformationUser написан с одним нижним подчеркиванием.